# Why I need to load my training data before loading my keras model?

Tags: python-3.x, text, keras

I'm building a chatbot with keras. I saw a guide on how to build a contextual chatbot, with a bag of words model.
The model is trained on a set of unique words, and learns to identify categories linked to certain words.
The documents list is a list of tuples with the words and their respective categorie or 'tag'.

Here is the link: https://medium.com/@ferrygunawan/build-facebook-messenger-contextual-chatbot-with-tensorflow-and-keras-4f8cc79438cf

After the model is built, I have a small script, where I receive user input (sentence) and that sentence is classified.
The classify function receives the input of the user (sentence) and the list of tokenized words, which is the same list of words that the model was trained on.

My question is: **Do I need to feed the model with his training data before I load the model? And if so, how can I overcome this and load the model and classify it without the need to load all of his training data again?**

```
def classify(sentence, words):
    # generate probabilities for the model   
    p = bow(sentence, words)
    print(p)
    d = len(p) 
    f = len(documents)-2
    a = np.zeros([f, d])
    tot = np.vstack((p,a))

    results = model.predict(tot)[0]
    return results

def bow(sentence, words):
    # tokenize the pattern

    sentence_words = clean_up_sentence(sentence)
    # bag of words
    print(words)
    bag = [0] * len(words)
    for s in sentence_words:
        for i,w in enumerate(words):
            if w == s:
                bag[i] = 1            
    return(np.array(bag))


def clean_up_sentence(sentence):
    sentence_words = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
    sentence_words = [stemmer.stem(word.lower()) for word in sentence_words]
    return sentence_words


#This is how I load the data, it is loaded in the same way in the script where the model is built

with open('teste.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig', newline='') as csv_file:
    csvReader = csv.DictReader(csv_file, delimiter = ';', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    data = list(csvReader)


intents = {}
intents['intents'] = data


words = []
classes = []
documents = []
ignore_words = ['?']


for intent in intents['intents']:
    pattern = intent['patterns']
    w = nltk.word_tokenize(pattern)
    words.extend(w)
    documents.append((w,intent['tag']))
    if intent['tag'] not in classes:
       classes.append(intent['tag'])



words = [stemmer.stem(w.lower()) for w in words if w not in ignore_words]
words = sorted(list(set(words)))

# remover duplicados na lista
classes = sorted(list(set(classes)))

model = keras.models.load_model ("model_test.h5")

sentence = input()
classify(sentence)
```

Comment: No, your question is not clear, you just say it does not make sense to you, which is not a question. You need to explain why it does not make sense to you, what exact part you are having trouble with.

Comment: I edited my question and I hope that I made it more clear

Comment: You train your model first and save the trained model. When you want to classify test data, you have to load the saved model and call `predict` on the model. Read some simple exaples on how models are trained and tested.